# Contract to contract send

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

I have a contract that sends a small fee to the owner. It works perfectly fine but when I change the owner to an address which contains another contract it always causes an error when viewed on the [block chain explorer](https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xD137C71085Ff24B1d6cf5aDDCd1bc18B43Ce1c60#internaltx) (that and the balance is never received by the receiving contract).

The bug seems to have been [recognized on Github](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/135) but I'm having trouble with the work around suggested:

```
address.call.value(_value)(_data)
```

My implementation looks like:

```
owner.call.value(fee);
```

It compiles fine but the fee is never sent. Am I doing it wrong or is this a current limitation of the platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often, when you send to another contract, you run into an out-of-gas error. This can be fixed by manually setting the gas that you want to supply, using the `.gas()` property.

```
owner.call.value(fee).gas(msg.gas-5000)();
```

This will supply all of the remaining gas, minus 5000 for any computations you need to do later. You can also use a fixed value, and adjust as needed. The call will return `true` if the transfer succeeded, and `false` if it ran out of gas and reverted, so check the value and plan accordingly.